# Footer links in magento 2

Tags: magento2, php, xml

Footer links are not properly aligned in the footer section.[image]

Comment: Share with me your project URL or code

Comment: Please share URL so that someone can check it and help.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. there was margin problem. Thank you